# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: ValueError

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model, ensemble-modeling, ensemble-learning

Today I am trying build `ensemble model`. Where I am working with iris dataset. In my model I am using `LogisticRegression, KNeighborsClassifier, RandomForestClassifier`. But when I am going run the program I get **ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10, 150]** error.
Below I am giving my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/iriscsv/Iris.csv')
df.head()
df
```

output --->

[image]

Then I am deleting id collumn from this dataset

```
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

After this I am used LabelEncoder on Species column

```
df['Species'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['Species'])
```

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.pairplot(df, hue = 'Species')
```

[image: Output]

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


clf1 = LogisticRegression()
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier()
clf3 = KNeighborsClassifier()

estimators = [('lr',clf1),('rf',clf2),('knn',clf3)]


for estimator in estimators:
    x = cross_val_score(estimator[1],x,y,cv=10,scoring='accuracy')
    print(estimator[0],np.round(np.mean(x),2))
```

After running the last estimator I am getting these error.

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd last line, you are overwriting the variable x, which previously held your input X data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81528)

Comment: @Icrmorin Did you read the question, and subsequently read my answer - or did you just see a single sentence and *assume*? The question is: "Why am I getting ValueError". My answer is that the 2nd last line, is being overwirtten, causing ValueError. A very direct answer. If you have a better one go ahead and answer it.

Comment: I will conceed there is merit to asking if this should be on stack overflow rather than data science.

Comment: Yeah the automatic wording is a bit bad. For this kind of question I would usually vote to close and provide an answer in comment. I am sorry if this gave you the impression you are at fault here.